# "Argument labels '(options:)' do not match any available overloads" occurs in PagingMenuController

Tags: cocoapods, swift3, xcode8

I use [PagingMenuController](https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController) 2.0.0 in my project using swift3.
I have a problem when I write following codes.
These codes are copied from README of [PagingMenuController](https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController).
An error "Argument labels '(options:)' do not match any available overloads" occurs in the last line.

```
struct MenuItem1: MenuItemViewCustomizable {}
    struct MenuItem2: MenuItemViewCustomizable {}

    struct MenuOptions: MenuViewCustomizable {
        var itemsOptions: [MenuItemViewCustomizable] {
            return [MenuItem1(), MenuItem2()]
        }
    }

    struct PagingMenuOptions: PagingMenuControllerCustomizable {
        var componentType: ComponentType {
            return .all(menuOptions: MenuOptions(), pagingControllers: [UIViewController(), UIViewController()])
        }
    }

    let options = PagingMenuOptions()
    let pagingMenuController = PagingMenuController(options: options)
```

Comment: The error message says that there is no `init`method with parameter `options`. Try `let pagingMenuController = PagingMenuController()`, `pagingMenuController.options = options`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried your suggestion, but an error "cannot invoke initializer for type 'PagingMenuController' with no arguments" occurred.